# awk: filter block only if specific line does not exist

Tags: awk, filtering

I got a text stream that looks something like this:

```
whatever => foo,
arg => 'some text
   over multiple lines
   sometimes',
bytes => 123,
...
```

What I'm interested in is the text between `arg =>` and `bytes =>`. So I filtered out the block with

```
cat mystream | awk '/arg =>/,/bytes =>/'
```

which works fine. But now I want to skip the whole block if there is one word somewhere in the text. Something like `grep -v` but for the whole block, not just the line. Any ideas? Thanks.

Note, this is not restricted to awk, it's just what came to my mind. Any other tool is fine, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using a /pat1/,/pat2/ range usually seems like a good idea but then as soon as you need to add a condition or do something else it falls flat. IMHO you're better off just using a flag like this:

```
awk '/arg =>/{f=1} f; /bytes =>/{f=0}' file
```

as that can be extended without a total re-write. In this case, just build up a record when you're in the range (i.e. when "f" is set) and print it if appropriate at the end of the range. This will always print it:

```
awk '/arg =>/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS} /bytes =>/{ if (f) printf "%s",rec; f=0}' file
```

and this will print it only if the text "whatever" appears in the record:

```
awk '/arg =>/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS} /bytes =>/{ if (f && (rec ~ "whatever")) printf "%s",rec; f=0}' file
```

and this will print it only if the text "whatever" does not appear in the record:

```
awk '/arg =>/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS} /bytes =>/{ if (f && (rec !~ "whatever")) printf "%s",rec; f=0}' file
```

This is the script from your comments below (reformatted slightly)

```
<tcpdump> |
awk '
   /arg =>/ {rec=""; f=1}
   f {rec = rec $0 ORS}
   /bytes =>/ {
      if (rec !~ /menuStructure|session/)
         printf "%s",rec
      f=0
   }
' | sed "s/.*bytes =>.*/\n----------\n/g" | sed "s/arg => //g"
```

Based on that, I think this script will do what you're trying to do:

```
<tcpdump> |
awk '
   /bytes =>/ {
      if (f && (rec !~ /menuStructure|session/))
         print rec "----------"
      f=0
   }
   f {rec = rec $0 ORS}
   sub(/arg =>/,"") {rec=$0; f=1}
'
```

Comment: @tombom you're welcome. I just updated it though to handle the case where the end pattern can appear twice before a subsequent begin pattern in your input file.

Comment: Another question, I was trying to do the following now `awk '/arg =>/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS}; /bytes =>/{ if (rec !~ "menuStructure" && rec !~ "session") printf "%s",rec; f=0}' | sed "s/.*bytes =>.*/\n----------\n/g" | sed "s/arg => //g"` Basically, just adding another pipe. But then it prints nothing. Without my addition it does. Why is that?

Comment: You didn't give it a file to read? Whatever you're trying to do, it can probably be done more elegantly inside the awk script rather than with a bunch of pipes and seds after it.

Comment: Input comes from a tcpdump, decrypted by another script. Basically I want to capture SQL queries while I click through a webshop. Trying to understand what a former colleague did (I'm no developer, just DB admin).

Comment: Could you help me to figure that out? When this works I'm done with it.

Comment: See my edits. I don't know why your sed/pipes stuff wasn't working, maybe something to do with DOS formatted input file or your use of double quotes instead of single quotes in your sed script, but it's simpler just to keep it all in awk anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20175/discussion-between-ed-morton-and-tombom)

Comment: Awesome, if only I could upvote you twice. Thank you very much!

Comment: Youre welcom and if your start/end patterns need to occur at the start of a line just stick "^" in front of arg and bytes so they become /^arg.../ and /^bytes.../.

Comment: Just added back my test for "f" that I lost in that final step.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/arg =>/,/bytes =>/ {s=s?s:NR;if($0~/some/)exit; a[NR]=$0;e=NR;}END{for(i=s;i<=e;i++)print a[i]}' file
```

the above oneliner will print nothing (based on your example) if your block containing "some".

Comment: Works, but a `Caught SIGPIPE` error is thrown. Thanks for your effort, but I can only accept it when this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it with GNU awk:

```
m1='arg =>'
m2='bytes =>'
pattern='some'
awk -v RS="$m1|$m2" -v start="$m1" -v end="$m2" -v pattern="$pattern" \
  'RT == end && $0 !~ pattern { print start $0 end }' < mystream
```

That is, split the stream at the start and end markers, then, when an end marker is found *and* the block doesn't contain `$pattern`, print it.

Note that `m1`, `m2` and `pattern` are all regular expressions, and so can be tweaked to your needs. Note also that this will not work if your input-block contains either `m1` or `m2`. Also see Ed's note below.

Comment: You need to anchor your RS or it will fail if it appears elsewhere than the start of a line. Also the OP wants to print up to the whole line that contains `bytes =>`, not up to just the text `bytes =>` so you'd need to make RS include something like `bytes =>.*\n` and then print RT instead of `end` on a match.